# METEOR: Fail to store data from external api

Tags: javascript, meteor

I need to store IP data of registered user. I'm using telize api for retrieving IP and `collection hooks` for updating after inserting new registered user.

**server/methods.js**

```
Meteor.methods({
  // The method expects a valid IPv4 address
  'geoIp': function () {
    // Construct the API URL
    this.unblock();
    var apiUrl = 'http://www.telize.com/geoip/';
    // query the API
    var response = HTTP.get(apiUrl);
    Meteor.users.update(
          {_id: this.userId}, 
          {$set: {ipdata: response}}
      )
  }
});
```

**lib/schemas.js**

```
  ipdata: {
    type: Object,
    optional: true
  }
```

**server/hooks.js**

```
Meteor.users.after.insert(function (userId, doc) {
  Meteor.call('geoIp');
});
```

These code resulting no error, successfully registering new user, but fail to store ipdata

Anyone have figured out what's wrong with my code?

thank You very much..

Comment: you should debug your code to see if you get a response or even if the hook gets called? `console.log()` can help a lot over here. Also why to call an API to get the IP of the user? You will get the IP of the server not the user. You can get the user IP in the meteor method with: `clientIP = this.connection.clientAddress;`

Comment: If you're trying to track user logins by IP address you can save yourself a lot of trouble by just using the excellent [mizzao:user-status](https://atmospherejs.com/mizzao/user-status) package

Comment: Actually, it's not IP. It's country and city of user login which only geoip has been provided,,,, i need to lock specific content based on country of user login

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure `this.userId` is not set in this case. You're calling `Meteor.call()` server-side and not from another method's body, so the called method has no context.

Instead, you'd probably want to just have a regular function for this. E.g.

```
addGeoIp = function(userId, ip){
    var response = HTTP.get(apiUrl);
    Meteor.users.update(userId, {$set: {ipdata: response}});
}

Meteor.users.after.insert(function (userId, doc) {
    addGeoIp(userId, ip);
});
```

Also, as Mark said, http://www.telize.com/geoip/ on its own would just return the server's IP, not the client's IP. So you need to pass the client's IP into the API to get the location.

Comment: Hi @Oskar thank you for your answer! Can you explain further how to pass client IP into telize. I just know that meteor have built in method to get clientIp..thank You,,

Comment: @KarinaL I don't know, I haven't used it. There must be some documentation for the API somewhere, I hope you can figure it out. I can only help with Meteor, not some external APIs.